# Renaming files based on the contents of a text file outside

Tags: files, scripting, rename

I have a file which contains the filenames and the rename detail. When i am using this script from the folder its running fine, but when I am trying to run it from outside I am getting error.

```
mv corebill_325035106_325000023-67-1.pdf TNZIUSALLC-00000181_77777700000360_08_325000023-67-1.pdf mv: cannot stat ‘core_325035106_325000023-67-1.pdf’: No such file or directory
```

Script:

```
while IFS=',' read -a files 
do 
   mv "${files[0]}" "${files[1]}" 
done < list.txt
```

Comment: provide absolute path to your directory path, so change `mv "${files[0]}" "${files[1]}"` to the directory path containing those files like `mv "/path/to/your/directory/${files[0]}" "/path/to/your/directory/${files[1]}"` and don't forget update the `list.txt` file path as well.

Comment: Thanks .. it helps :)